# How to download test network in testnet with mist and run smart contracts using solidity on remix - ide?

Tags: solidity, remix, mist, testnets, rinkeby

I followed a youtube video, the link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEULs3ShTxo&list=PLnwIwnzAHNfi3mCaRDIXcQx8HtuWm1pqw&index=2

He said that while installing MIST, while downloading mist, he said that it will ask whether to download main network or testnet network. But it wasn't asked while i am downloading!! Also when installed mist, to select test network there are two networks one is ropsten and other is rinkeby. As per video I have selected Rinkeby network. When i am trying to create a new account -> the account is not creating eventhough i created(creation process, password and confirm password)!! Please tell me why it is happening!!﻿ The account is not created and the further process I am getting to continue as per the video.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ropsten & Rinkeby :

**Ropsten**

- PoW ( proof of work)
- Supported by geth and parity
- Best reproduces the current production environment
- Chaindata size 15 GB - Apr 2018

**Rinkeby**

- PoA (Immune to spam attacks)
- Supported by geth only
- Chaindata size 6 GB - Apr 2018

If need support on both geth and parity go wtih Ropsten. Otherwise choose Kovan or Rinkeby as they are more stable.

===================================

**Detailed version below:**

**Ropsten**

- PoW testnet
- History:

  Started in November 2016. Named after a subway station in Stockholm.
  Was DoS attacked in February 2017 which made synching slow and made 
  clients consume a lot of disk space.
  Was revived in March 2017 and became usable again.
- Pros:

  Best reproduces the current production environment, i.e. system and 
  network conditions on the live Ethereum mainnet, because it's PoW net.
  Can be used with both geth and parity.
- Ether can be mined. Or requested from a faucet:

  https://faucet.metamask.io/
- Cons:

  Not immune to spam attacks. Because of this it's less stable.

  Network id: 3

  Block time: sub-30 seconds
- Commands:

  geth --testnet or geth --networkid 3
  parity --chain ropsten
  Explorer https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

---

**Rinkeby**

PoA testnet started by the Ethereum team. Uses Clique PoA consensus protocol.

- History:

  Started in April 2017. Named after a metro station in Stockholm.
- Pros:

  Immune to spam attacks (as Ether supply is controlled by trusted parties)
- Cons:

  Supported by geth only
  Doesn't fully reproduce the current production environment as it uses PoA.
- Ether can't be mined. It has to be requested from a faucet:

  https://faucet.rinkeby.io/
- Network id: 4
- Block time: 15 seconds
- **Command:**

  geth --rinkeby or geth --networkid 4
  Explorer https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/

---

If you want to deploy your contract on ropsten/rinkeby testnet using remix/metamask or mist please read my blog : [Deploy your smart contract](https://medium.com/@techgeek628/deploy-your-smart-contract-1851ac213b8b)